# Integrate Ionic and Wikitude

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, wikitude

I am working in integrate the wikitude cordova plugin into an existing Ionic app, but cant get it works.

I follow the setup guide for cordova in this link:
http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/setupguidecordovacli.html#PhoneGapExistingApp

Then I try to follow the POI guide in this link:
http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/poi.html#point-of-interest-poi

But am not able to get it work.

Can someone help me please?

Edit:
I get a blank screen and nothing about POI's
[image: running in genymotion]

Comment: Please explain exactly what your problem is, show some code, error messages...

Comment: any luck with your project? i am trying also but still failing

Comment: no progress, it would be good if someone upload a working example on github....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the needed plugins?

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera cordova-plugin-media-capture cordova-plugin-device-orientation cordova-plugin-geolocation

cordova build
```

Also, you can't use an emulator, you need to use a real device.